# Why do my functions run a million miles an hour?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The enemy1, enemy2, and enemy3 functions should run instantaniously using the ontimer function, moving the turtles inside them while running a nested checkcollision function to check if the turtles collide with the user. Along that running a nested checkbullet function to check distance see if they collide with the bullet turtle, and a nested check earth function to check their distance from the earth turtle which is the blue circle in the bottom right of the screen. However these 3 functions are running at hypersonic speed and I can't seem to find out why.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random
from random import randint

#screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(3)
#user
player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.color("green")
player.penup()
#First enemy
player2 = Turtle()
player2.color("green")
player2.shape('turtle')
player2.penup()
player2.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player2.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
#Second enemy
player3 = Turtle()
player3.color("green")
player3.shape('square')
player3.penup()
player3.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player3.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
#third enemy
player4 = Turtle()
player4.color("green")
player4.shape('triangle')
player4.penup()
player4.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player4.setheading(random.randint(1,360))

#earth

earth = Turtle()
earth.penup()
earth.shape("circle")
earth.color("blue")
earth.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5.6, stretch_len = 5.6)
earth.setpos(150,-150)

#bullet
bullet = Turtle()
bullet.shape("turtle")
bullet.color("purple")
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup()
bullet.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup()
px = 0
py = 0

def up():
    global px
    global py
    py = player.ycor() + 5

    if py >= 200:
        py -= 15

    player.sety(py)

def down():
    global px
    global py
    py = player.ycor() - 5

    if py < -200:
        py += 15

    player.sety(py)

def left():
    global px
    global py
    px = player.xcor() - 5

    if px <= -200:
        px += 15

    player.setx(px)

def right():
    global px
    global py
    px = player.xcor() + 5

    if px >= 200:
        px -= 15 

    player.setx(px)




#distance calculator
def checkcollision(t1, t2):
    while t1.distance(t2) < 10:
        t2.setpos(randint(-100, 100), randint(-100, 100))

# the x and y distance that the player2 turtle moves 
dx = 5
dy = 5

damage = 0

def checkbullet(bullet,turtle):
    while bullet.distance(turtle) < 10:
        turtle.hideturtle()

def check_earth(planet,turtle):
    global damage
    damage+=1
    while planet.distance(turtle)>10:
        turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

#1st enemy(switch heading)
head = 0
def enemy1():
    checkcollision(player,player2)
    check_earth(earth,player2)
    global head
    player2.fd(5)

    x2, y2 = player2.position()
    head = player2.heading()

    if y2 <= -200 or y2 >= 200:
        player2.fd(0)
        player2.backward(7.5)
        player2.setheading((head)* -1)

    if x2 <= -200 or x2 >= 200:
        player2.fd(0)
        player2.backward(7.5)
        if head < 90:
            player2.setheading(0 - ((head) * 2))
        if head>90<179:

            player2.setheading((head)/2)

        if head>179<260:
            player2.setheading((head)/3)


        if head>260<361:
            player2.setheading((head)/2)

    screen.ontimer(enemy1,50)

#Second enemy(dx,dy)
def enemy2():
    checkcollision(player, player3)
    check_earth(earth,player3)


    global dx
    global dy
    x3, y3 = player3.position()

    player3.setposition(x3 + dx, y3 + dy)


    if y3 <= -200 or y3 >= 200:
        dy *= -1
        player3.sety(y3 + dy)

    if x3 <= -200 or x3 >= 200:
        dx *= -1
        player3.setx(x3 + dx)


    screen.ontimer(enemy2,50)

def enemy3():
    checkcollision(player,player4)
    check_earth(earth,player4)

    player4.fd(5)
    x4, y4 = player4.position()
    head3 = player4.heading()

    if y4 <= -200 or y4 >= 200:
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.backward(7.5)
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.setheading((head3)* -1)

    if x4 <= -200 or x4 >= 200:
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.backward(7.5)
        player4.fd(0)
        if head3 < 90:
            player4.setheading(0 - ((head3) * 2))
        if head3>90<179:
            player4.setheading((head3)/2)

        if head3>179<260:
            player4.setheading((head3)/3)


        if head3>260<361:
            player4.setheading((head3)/2)
    screen.ontimer(enemy3,50)

#When bullet hits wall   
def bullet_end():
    screen.listen()   
    screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
    screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
    screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
    screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
    screen.onkeyrelease(shoot_key,"w")


def shoot_key():


    bullet.setposition(px,py)
    bullet.shape("circle")
    bullet.showturtle()
    bullet.penup()

    def shoot():
        checkbullet(bullet,player2)
        checkbullet(bullet,player3)
        checkbullet(bullet,player4)
        bx = bullet.xcor()
        by = bullet.ycor()
        bullet.fd(5)
        if bx>=200 or bx<=-200:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.backward(7.5)
            bullet_end()
        if by>=200 or by<=-200:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.backward(7.5)
            bullet_end()

        screen.ontimer(shoot,50)
    shoot()
screen.listen() 
screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
screen.onkeyrelease(shoot_key,"w")



enemy1()
enemy2()
enemy3()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: In general it is nicer to write the shortest possible piece of code exhibiting your problem.

This helps as people don't have to skim through all the lines of the code to identify  the one causing the issue.

Comment: Indeed…please provide a [mre], emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: def enemy1():
    checkcollision(player,player2)
    check_earth(earth,player2)
    global head
    player2.fd(5)
There's more missing from the function in the above code that I couldn't reply with as it can't fit, so check the code above for reference if needed. Anyhow the function is ran on a timer of 50 milli-seconds and inside the turtle is being moved 5 pixels and 2 nested functions are ran. These nested functions are checkcollision(player,player2) and check_earth(earth,player2). You'll see when the program it runs the turtles move much faster than they'r set

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the function `check_earth`. As far as I can see, you are trying to prevent the enemy from being too close to earth - if it gets there, it should receive a new, random position. Obviously, this new position also shouldn't be too near to earth, so you are doing it in a loop. However, there are three errors in the loop.

Firstly, the condition for looking for a new position: `while planet.distance(turtle)>10:` is always met for a valid place.

Secondly, you immediately move the enemy to new random position, without checking the condition, which creates a lot of traffic. Instead, you should set position only when you are sure that it's correct.

Lastly, where did the '10' value come from? To declare your circle's size, you used: `earth.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5.6, stretch_len = 5.6)`. There is a following dependency between earth radius and stretch length: `2*RADIUS/CURSOR_SIZE`. As default value of CURSOR_SIZE is 20, it would mean that the radius of your circle is 56. If we want to detect the collision as soon as any part of enemy's turtle touches the earth, we should also add the length of the enemy's cursor.

So, instead of:

```
def check_earth(planet,turtle):
    global damage
    damage+=1
    while planet.distance(turtle)>10:
        turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))
```

You should define function `check_earth` as:

```
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
EARTH_RADIUS = 56
def check_earth(planet,turtle):
    global damage
    damage+=1

    (turtle_x, turtle_y) = turtle.pos()
    while True:
        if planet.distance(turtle_x, turtle_y) > EARTH_RADIUS + CURSOR_SIZE:
            turtle.setpos(turtle_x,turtle_y)
            break

        turtle_x = random.randint(-200,200)
        turtle_y = random.randint(-200,200)
```

Comment: I added your change and that made the functions run the speed that they should however nothing happens when the enemy turtles collide with the earth turtle. They just pass through as if the checkearth function isn't working at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The short answer is that 10 is too low, there should be 76. The longer answer is in my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Not: while planet.distance(turtle)>10:
   Yes: while planet.distance(turtle)<10:
   The solution was simple and we both overlooked it,
   I ask dumb questions sometimes. Anyways thanks for helping